# How i can verify the signal in a unit test of Camunda process?

Tags: unit-testing, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

We use [camunda-bpm-assert](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-assert) and [camunda-bpm-assert-scenario](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-assert-scenario/) libs for Camunda  **processes unit testing** (testing of `.bpmn`).

But i couldn't find any approach for **signal** testing - how can we *verify, that signal with the right name and variables was thrown* during test execution?

Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It's a workaround, but if this is important to test, you could deploy another process in your test scenario that receives a signal and has a follow up task (or execution listener) that records the call and the variables, thus allowing you to assert on these.